# Build an array using Ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to build an array using ajax. The array 'test' have a good structure, but the array 'translations' have a bad structure (Check my console output)

Chrome console:
[image: chrome console]

Edge console:
[image: edge console]

Firefox console:
[image: firefox console]

So what should I change in my code to have array 'translations' structure same as array 'test' structure

Here is my function:

```
function translateAllCaptions(dropdownId) {
var selectedLanguageValue = getDropDownSelectedLanguageValue(dropdownId);
var selectedLanguage = "";
var translations = [];
translations.push(["Caption", "Translation"]);


// Get translation language
selectedLanguageValue ? selectedLanguage = getLanguage(selectedLanguageValue) : console.log("Language dropdown error");

// Translate all captions
// Get all captions
var captions = getAllCaptions();

captions.forEach(caption => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            source: 'en',
            target: selectedLanguage,
            q: caption
        },
        success: function (result) {
            translations.push([caption, result.data.translations[0].translatedText]);
        }
    }); 
});
var test = [
    ['Caption', 'Translation'],
    ['Software', 'Logiciel'],
    ['Network', 'Réseau'],
    ['Hardware', 'Matériel']
]
// Create and download
console.log(test);
console.log(translations);
exportToCsv("Translations.csv", translations);  
}
```

Comment: Ok, chrome looks to report something weird, but the expanded structure looks the same to me.

Comment: Visullay yes, but when I use the function :
`exportToCsv("Translations.csv", test); ` this works.
`exportToCsv("Translations.csv", translations);` this doesn't work.
That means that my 2 arrays are different

Comment: What gives you `JSON.serialize(translation)`?

Comment: `JSON.serialize(translations) ` shows an error

Comment: Sorry, `.stringify()` is the method you should check.

Comment: `.stringify()` Doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by that? `console.log(JSON.stringify(translation))` doesn't give any result?

Comment: It shows this in the console `[["Caption","Translation"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax requests are started asynchronously. That means, that the `forEach` completes way before the requests are finished. But by when you expand the result in the developer console, they do complete, and you see the result. This is really misleading. The workaround is to wait for them before processing the result. The syntax is quite awkward, but it should work:

```
var requests = captions.map(caption => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            source: 'en',
            target: selectedLanguage,
            q: caption
        },
        success: function (result) {
            translations.push([caption, result.data.translations[0].translatedText]);
        }
    }); 
});

$.when.apply($, requests).then(function(deferreds) {
    exportToCsv("Translations.csv", translations);  
})
```

If you need to return the `translations` array from this function, then you will need to get more deeply involved with promises and async-await, but this is enough for the export to work.

**[Update]**

You wrote in your comment, that it does not work. Then you are doing something else wrong. As I don't have the rest of your code and your API key, I have prepared a simple demo below. It is using an API that simply echoes the request. But as you will see it is writing to the console only when all three requests complete, and there will be three elements in the array.

```js
let sources = ['blue','red','green'];
let results = [];

let requests = sources.map(color => $.getJSON(`http://mockbin.org/request?color=${color}`).then(r => results.push(r.queryString)));

$.when.apply($, requests).then(() => console.log(results));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks also me I found a weired solution, I change this in my old code 
` success: function (result) {
                i++;

                translationsArray.push([caption, result.data.translations[0].translatedText]);
         
                if (i == captions.length) {
                    exportToCsv("Translations.csv", translationsArray);
                } 
            }`

Comment: Yeah, this wil work too. But it is not the way to handle async.

Comment: Yes I see :D my loop go faster than the async call it self :) As result I saw that my generated entries in the csv file are not in the exact order (using my method ). THANK YOU

Comment: I tried your code, but It doesn't work :), I got only the CSV file with the header, when I `console.log(translations)` I got the same error as me yesterday, an array showing 4 element but in only contains 1 element

Comment: can I pass an array of captions to `data: {
            key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            source: 'en',
            target: selectedLanguage,
            q: captions
        },` Something like that ?

Comment: I doubt you can pass array to the translation service, however, you can have multiple `q`-s (see: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text). Btw the method I have suggested certainly works. See update.

Comment: I tried It but it doesn't because the array contains only the header, if you build your array manually like I did before It will works

Comment: Also [in your link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text) there is only 1 q, it's not possible to include more than 1 text to translate

Comment: Read carefully: _... You can provide multiple strings of text to translate by including multiple q parameters in your JSON..._

Comment: I understand this point, but How can I include multiple q ? What the code looks like? thanks
I found this as well: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate